# ggplot geom_vline with binary variable and x-axis dates and long data format

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-vline

I am trying to create a plot where I have a vline corrispondent to the crisis quarter (crisis variable is binary 1 (crisis)-0 (no-crisis). The piece of code

```
geom_vline(xintercept = as.yearqtr(c("2016-01- 
01","2017-01-01")), linetype=4)+ #I should have a line only 
in the date where che crisis is 1 (different per each 
country)
```

Should allow me to have a stright line when the crisis variable is 1.

Here a working example:

```
# Load Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

date <- as.yearqtr(c("2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06","2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06","2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06"))
variable <- c('var1','var1','var1','var2','var2','var2','crisis','crisis','crisis')
value <- c(12,15,18,120,155,175,0,0,1)
specification <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
country <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT","AT","AT","AT","AT","AT")

df1 <- data.frame(country, date, variable, specification, value)
View(df1)

date <- as.yearqtr(c("2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06","2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06","2015-01-01","2016-03-01","2017-04-06"))
variable <- c('var1','var1','var1','var2','var2','var2','crisis','crisis','crisis')
value <- c(15,17,221,150,135,155,0,1,0)
specification <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
country <- c("BE","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE")

df2 <- data.frame(country, date, variable, specification, value)
View(df2)



df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)
View(df3)

ch_1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df3[df3$specification == levels(factor(df3$specification))[1] & df3$variable == "var1" ,], 
            aes(x = date, 
                y = value,
                #colour = specification ##in the actual code this is uncommented
                ))+
  geom_line(data = df3[df3$specification == levels(factor(df3$specification))[1] & df3$variable == "var2" ,], 
            aes(x = date, 
                y = value,
                #colour = specification ##in the actual code this is uncommented
                ))+

  #should change here ---
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.yearqtr(c("2016-01-01","2017-01-01")), linetype=4)+ #I should have a line only in the date where che crisis is 1 (different per each country)
  # ---------------------
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = 'free_y')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1,face="bold",size=9))

ch_1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correct, "2016-01-01" is meant for AT and "2017-01-01" for BE. So you need to specify this group in geom_vline for it to allocate to the correct panel:

Make data frame for crisis years with country:

```
crisis_year=df3[df3$value == 1,c("country","date")]
```

Plot, making sure to pass this into geom_vline:

```
ch_1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df3[df3$specification == levels(factor(df3$specification))[1] & df3$variable == "var1" ,], 
            aes(x = date, 
                y = value
                #colour = specification ##in the actual code this is uncommented
                ))+
  geom_line(data = df3[df3$specification == levels(factor(df3$specification))[1] & df3$variable == "var2" ,], 
            aes(x = date, 
                y = value
                ))+
  geom_vline(data=crisis_year,aes(xintercept = date), linetype=4)+
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = 'free_y')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1,face="bold",size=9))

ch_1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. In the first piece of code I might need of something to create this from scrath. I mean not imput manually information about countries and crisis date but starting from the existent dataset. Would you have any input from this side?

Comment: Can give it a shot.. How do you get this from df3?

Comment: If you write df3$date[df3$value == 1] instead of the dates inside the ggplot you get the correct dates. But the problem is that they are not referenced to the countries

Comment: @A_Bed, see above, is it correct? And the crisis year is different from what you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little messy but you must filter the data when calling `geom_vline`. Try:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df3[df3$specification == levels(factor(df3$specification))[1] & df3$variable == "var1" ,], 
            aes(x = date, 
                y = value,
                #colour = specification ##in the actual code this is uncommented
            ))+
  geom_line(data = df3[df3$specification == levels(factor(df3$specification))[1] & df3$variable == "var2" ,], 
            aes(x = date, 
                y = value,
                #colour = specification ##in the actual code this is uncommented
            )) +
  geom_vline(data = df3[df3$variable == "crisis" & 
                          df3$value == 1 & df3$country == "AT",], aes(xintercept = date), linetype=4) + 
  geom_vline(data = df3[df3$variable == "crisis" & 
                          df3$value == 1 & df3$country == "BE",], aes(xintercept = date), linetype=4) + 
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = 'free_y')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1,face="bold",size=9))
```

Comment: Nice solution, i have 19 countries and it's not possible to reference all of them in the plot, would be too messy.